# How can I use axios to make get requests and store the result object to a variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Hi I am new to react and at the moment I want to make simple GET requests to an api but all I get is a `Promise <pending>` when I try to console.log it out

I have the following function

```js
let user = axios.get('/api/v1/users/id/' + userid)
  .then(response => response.data)
  .then( data => { console.log( data ); return data });

console.warn(user);
```

and it should return a user object and store it in a variable so that I can use it later but it does not work

What have I done wrong here and is there a better way to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call for how to return values from async calls. Also, consider using `async/await`, as it will make things much easier to understand.

Comment: Welcome to asynchronous programming in JavaScript! You need to `await` your response, such as `let user = await axois.get(...)`